Do I need to get a B2 visa for tourist travel from USA to India if I already have a B1 Visa?
I am an American citizen with a US passport and have been invited to a wedding in India. I already have a B1-Multi Entry VISA that I obtained for business travel on a previous trip. I'm no longer with the company that I used to travel there for business.
How flexible are they with personal travel under a B1 VISA? I'm worried they might deny me entry if I can't substantiate a current business reason when entering the country.

I'm confused by a few things in your question.  B1 & B2 visas are usually mentioned in relation to visits TO the United States, as those are the names for the business and tourism visitor visas in the US.  As far as I know India doesn't also call theirs B1 or B2 (but maybe I am mistaken here).  Further, I believe all US citizens need to visit India is an e-visa that can be applied for online relatively quickly and easily.  But you're correct, traveling on a business visa for a wedding may not be allowed.

On the VISA stamp in my passport it says Visa Type: B-1. Probably better safe than sorry, if it is quick to get the e-VISA I guess I'll just do that.

@Midavalo as far as I can tell with some quick online research, Indian business visas are indeed issued with type code "B", but tourist visas (including the one I personally got some years ago) are issued with type code "T". In any event, yeah, US citizens should nowadays probably get an e-Visa instead of either of these unless there are some special circumstances, but I am not sure what would happen in the case of someone who, as the question asks, already has a B visa but shows up at the border and asks to enter for non-business purposes.

That's it strange, my USA tourist visa was issued as B1/B2. Are you sure your visa is only B1 or is that only on the stamp?

@André They're not talking about a US tourist visa.  They're asking about a visa to visit India
